# Send value from database to checkbox checked

Tags: php, html, pdo

I have a table with 3 fields `looking_id`,`user_id`,`looking`. `looking_id` is unique.

```
$sql="SELECT looking_id,user_id,looking FROM `provider_service_need` WHERE `user_id`='$user_id'";
$stmt=$dbg->query($sql);
<input type="checkbox" name="What_services[]" id="What_services" value="person_care" <?php if($stmt=='person_care')echo checked;?> >
<input type="checkbox" name="What_services[]" id="What_services" value="child_care" <?php if($stmt=='child_care')echo checked;?> >
<input type="checkbox" name="What_services[]" id="What_services" value="pet_care" <?php if($stmt=='pet_care')echo checked;?> >
```

but it's not working.

Comment: _"but it's not working."_ What isn't working?

Comment: Which table column holds those values?

Comment: $stmt is not a single value, but an array. Try parsing $stmt['looking_id'] (I guess that this is the column you want).

Comment: You need to do  `foreach ($stmt->query($sql) as $row) {
        print $row['looking_id'] . "\t"; print $row['user_id'] . "\t";`

Comment: Separate PHP from HTML and don't use identical `input` `id` names, they are supposed to be unique.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$sql="SELECT looking_id,user_id,looking FROM `provider_service_need` WHERE `user_id`='$user_id'";
$stmt=mysql_query($sql);
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($stmt))
{
?>
<input type="checkbox" name="What_services[]" id="What_services_<?php echo $result['looking'];?>" value="person_care" <?php if($result['looking']=='person_care')echo "checked";?> >
<?php
} ?>
```

Comment: OP use `pdo` not `mysql` you can also check the `tag` in question!! **FYI** mysql is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

For pdo try this

```
$sql="SELECT looking_id,user_id,looking FROM `provider_service_need` WHERE `user_id`='$user_id'";
foreach ($stmt->query($sql) as $row)
{
?>
<input type="checkbox" name="What_services[]" id="What_services_<?php echo $row['looking'];?>" value="person_care" <?php if($row['looking']=='person_care')echo "checked";?> >
<?php
} ?>
```